# タイムラインを管理できるAnimationライブラリでオススメなどあれば教えてください。

Tags: javascript

**Three.jsを使い、アニメーションを制作しようとしています。**

タイムラインの管理が出来るAnimationライブラリを探していて、`TweenMax.js`が便利そうだと感じました。
しかし、他の選択肢も考えうると思うので、もしよろしければ、他のアニメーションライブラリなどの雑感など教えていただければ幸いです。

参考までに、欲しい機能としては、

- アニメーションとTweenの基本的な機能
- タイムライン管理機能
- コードの保守性

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ターゲットブラウザがモダンブラウザなら、animejsとかも使いやすいかと思います。http://animejs.com/documentation/